# Xampp, mysql crashes each time I start it

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I try to start mysql, it shuts down:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

This is what the logs say:

```
019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 

'D:\a\dec8\xammp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\a\dec8\xammp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 113890; transaction id 9

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\a\dec8\xammp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191230 11:38:45

2019-12-30 11:38:45 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I've watched multiple videos and none of which show me how to correct this. This has happened to me before and I simply reinstalled xammp and that worked fine. However I don't want to do that this time and recreate my db. I want to know how to fix it. Also, if there is a better place to ask this question, please tell me.

Comment: Anything useful in the event viewer?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: You can launch it like so: https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/ . Once it’s open, try looking under “Applications” or “Services” for anything that may be XAMPP related. I also assume you checked for open ports? MySQL requires port 3306 to be available by default, so if any open application uses it, it will fail to start. Skype, for example, uses ports dynamically and could conflict with MySQL. So if you have Skype autostarting, this could be the issue.

Comment: Yes I've checked for open ports. I changed the port to 81 to see if it will change anything. It didn't so I changed it back to 3306. This is weird because the problem had not started until this morning. I also don't have skype.

Comment: I found this error:  ` `The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
 and APPID 
{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}
 to the user LAPTOP-JUJPH32Q\nicko SID (S-1-5-21-2756851836-2014864518-3306798039-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0... etc ` `

Comment: I don’t think that’s related... the event viewer is chock full of entries that are technically accurate but entirely useless. :) The MySQL log file you posted just ends like this? Are there any other entries?

Comment: I'm just going to reinstall xampp. That seems to be the easiest solution, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full

Increase the setting for that file.

Look for complex queries that are needing a huge temp table.

> buffer pool, total size = 16M

That is a terribly small value.  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: where to do that? i mean where is related file located and what keys are to be updated

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt - In the configuration file -- probably `my.cnf`.  The second item is controlled by `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: I have the identical issue; the 2nd option does not work. I'd like to try the first, but where's the *setting for that file*?

Comment: @Codesmith - There are many possible locations for the MySQL configuration file.  It may (or may not) be called `my.cnf`.  XAMPP may (or may not) have documentation on where it is.

Comment: @RickJames, no worries. I got it to start again by deleting the `multi-master.info` file. But after it started, I found some of my db tables were corrupt. I just reinstalled XAMPP completely and haven't had issues since. (I did kinda lose some of my dbs.. nothing important though)